# NumPy append to 1-column vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to cluster pixels using k-means in an image (480 x 640), and so I am trying to initialise an empty numpy array, which represents a 1-column vector.

What I am trying to achieve is get all pixel values from the 2D array and add them in a 1D vertical vector, like this:

```
[ [ value ],
  [ value ],
  ...
  [ value ] ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the final pixel (with the 640 x 480 dimension remaining constant) or are you adding a column so the new dimension will be 641 x 480?

Comment: maybe I wrote my code wrong, but I am trying to achieve the Matlab equivalent of this: [value, value, value .... ] vertically. Basically trying to get the pixels from the image and add them to a single, 1D column vector

Comment: I don't think `append` is the right method here. Could you show us exactly what the input (`array`) and the output (`X`) should look like?

Comment: I wrote in my edited comment. Sorry

Comment: do you want to replace the zeros with the values? or are you trying to make the array longer?

Comment: yes, replace the zeros with the values. Just like doing X[i][j] = value

Comment: try `X=array.flatten()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `numpy.reshape()` what you want?

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
a.reshape(6,1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

Comment: I have a normal array, and I want to get every value in that array and move into an array as described by you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a matrix 640 x 480:

```
>>> a=np.arange(640*480).reshape(640,480)
>>> a
array([[     0,      1,      2, ...,    477,    478,    479],
       [   480,    481,    482, ...,    957,    958,    959],
       [   960,    961,    962, ...,   1437,   1438,   1439],
       ..., 
       [305760, 305761, 305762, ..., 306237, 306238, 306239],
       [306240, 306241, 306242, ..., 306717, 306718, 306719],
       [306720, 306721, 306722, ..., 307197, 307198, 307199]])
```

You can assign a columnar value like so:

```
>>> a[:,479]=0
>>> a
array([[     0,      1,      2, ...,    477,    478,      0],
       [   480,    481,    482, ...,    957,    958,      0],
       [   960,    961,    962, ...,   1437,   1438,      0],
       ..., 
       [305760, 305761, 305762, ..., 306237, 306238,      0],
       [306240, 306241, 306242, ..., 306717, 306718,      0],
       [306720, 306721, 306722, ..., 307197, 307198,      0]])
#                                                         ^^^ Note the 0 here
```

You can get the columnar value like so:

```
>>> a[:,478]
array([   478,    958,   1438,   1918, ..., 306238, 306718, 307198])
```